# Critique: Is this a good way to present images and captions for research document?

Tags: images, resource-recommendations, critique

I have put lots of pictures/images in my document and I would like to refer them. Below is my attemption after reading [this](http://www.magazinedesigning.com/what-to-do-with-picture-captions/).
[image]
What do you think about the font, the alignment, the size of images, etc? Can you give me some advices? Thank you.

Comment: Althougt Academia is also suitable for this question, I think only this site is best because I don't ask about what information I have missed or stuff like that, I'm asking about the good looking. I have edited my question, please come and see.

Comment: Is this also related to your dissertation? Will you be printing it in color or black and white?

Comment: Hi @Ryan, yes it is. It will be printed in color.

Comment: Please visit our [Critique guidelines](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work) before your question gets voted to be closed for being off-topic.

Comment: @Matt, I have read the guidelines and I still don't know how to improve it. I have image, I have specific questions (font, alignment, etc), I encourage the answerers. I can't give many detail as the examples give because I'm not a designer, I just feel something is missing or not good but can't point it out. Also, I just have found that StackExchange has [Writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com/), is this kind of questions more suitable in there? I think no because I want to know how to make a good look, not how to make a good story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it looks fine since it will be printed in color as long as it makes sense in the larger scheme of your document. The only suggestion I have is since you're printing in color, keep the blue for links but get rid of the underline. It will make them easier to read. You might also consider doing the link with at least the source name like:

National Institute of Health (http://nih.gov/science/)

Nature: International weekly journal of science (http://www.nature.com/news/drug-brings-hiv-out-of-hiding-1.10180)

---

But really you should probably check a style guide. Maybe the AMA (American Medical Association) if there is no style guide in your country.

According to http://www.evansville.edu/libraries/ama.cfm the correct format for websites is:

> INTERNET SOURCES
>   
> Citations to Internet sources aren't as rigid as those surrounding books and articles. If you have doubts about what to include, usually the quick rule is "more is better". Important elements to include are:
>
> - Author(s)' last name and first and middle initials (if known)
> - Name of article/webpage
> - If it is an abstract, note in [brackets] - OR
> - Name of journal, if appropriate, with a [serial online] notation, followed by year;volume:pages
> - Phrase "Available at:" and the URL of the page
> - Phrase "Accessed" and the date you looked at it
>
> Each element is followed by a period.
>
> 1. Henkel J. Testicular Cancer: Survival High with Early Treatment. FDA Consumer magazine [serial online]. January-February 1996. Available at: http://www.fda.gov/fdac/features/196_test.html. Accessed August 31, 1998.
> 2. Salvatore S. Study links lupus to Epstein Barr virus. [CNN website]. December 15, 1997. Available at: http://cnn.com/HEALTH/9712/15/lupus.discovery/. Accessed August 31, 1998.
> 3. Chabner E, Nixon A, Gelman R, et al. Family history and treatment outcome in young women after breast-conserving surgery and radiation therapy for early-stage breast cancer [abstract]. Journal of Clinical Oncology [serial online]. 1998;16:2045-2051. Available at: http://www.jcojournal.org/abs16_6/v16n6p2045.html. Accessed August 31, 1998.

---

Oh but make sure they're aligned the same. Consistency, consistency, consistency. Right now the top image has the caption one line up from the bottom. The second caption is aligned with the bottom. The third one looks like your screenshot was cut so its hard to say.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll take that. About guide style, I do have recommendation but also I can choose them freely, as long as the thesis contain full information. About AMA, they only say about word references, not image references. I also don't know if it's best to cite the authors and websites of the images because they are also freely in the internet, one Google click is easily to find them. Not only that, the consequence is I don't know the origin sources. However I'll rethink about that.

Comment: +1 to Ryan's suggestions, adding to that, if you really want to add the links to the data that you are presenting, QR-Codes would be the best supporting Graphic that would allow quicker access of the information and the page that would give better insights for the content in the research document.